# Downloading PDFs with requests and scrapy

Tags: python, pdf, scrapy, python-requests

So I've been trying to use the requests library in the pipeline to attempt to download PDFs. However the PDFs are always 0 bytes when downloaded. And I get an Error: error processing URL that traces back to the line where I makes the original requests though I can't seem to find what's wrong based on previous questions and documentation I've read. The URL is passed in through the Item URL field. Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import requests

class SherlockPipeline(object):

 def process_item(self,item, spider):
    #pdf_url = []
    #pdf_url.append(item['url'])
    pdf_url = item['url']
    local_filename = item['url'].split('/')[-1]
    request = requests.request('GET', pdf_url)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb' ) as f:
       for buff in request.iter_content(128): 
            f.write(buff)#write it to file
    return item
```

The log output is the following:

```
2015-12-03 17:42:42 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] INFO: Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.privacybydesign.ca
2015-12-03 17:42:42 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: "GET/content/uploads/2014/09/pbd-de-identifcation-essential.pdf HTTP/1.1" 302 275
2015-12-03 17:42:42 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] INFO:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.privacybydesign.ca
2015-12-03 17:42:43 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'url': u'http://www.privacybydesign.ca/content/uploads/2014/09/pbd-de-identifcation-essential.pdf'}
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\pinky\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
  current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "C:\Users\pinky\Documents\work\sherlock\sherlock\pipelines.py", line 16, in process_item
  request = requests.request('GET', pdf_url)
File "C:\Users\pinky\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
   response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\pinky\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
   resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\pinky\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 597, in send
   history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
File "C:\Users\pinky\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 195, in resolve_redirects
   **adapter_kwargs
File "C:\Users\pinky\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\pinky\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 433, in send
  raise SSLError(e, request=request)
```

Comment: Can reproduce your error, are you behind a proxy? What happens if you use `urllib` to download `https://www.privacybydesign.ca/content/uploads/2014/09/pbd-de-identifcation-essential.pdf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't change anything in the pipeline to solve the issue, so I changed the spider to yield a dictionary instead of an item and that worked, though I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy already has pipelines to [download files and images](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-files-pipeline)  which works well.

Comment: I specifically wanted to use the requests library.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `requests` with `stream` keyword argument as **True**:

```
request = requests.get(pdf_url, stream=True)
```

Also, as you may see, there is no need to make requests like this:

```
request = requests.request('GET', pdf_url, stream=True)
```

For more information regarding `stream`, please see:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow